# R Shiny App, Dynamic Slider Value

Tags: r, shiny

I need a slider value to be dynamic based of an external function. Here I have made it based of runif(...), however, for my real-world app, it is a web call to retrieve a value from the internet which may change once a day or something like that.

**global.R**

```
dynamicValue = function(){
  runif(1)
}
```

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
     shiny::sidebarPanel(
       sliderInput("slider",
                   "SliderInput",
                   min   = 0,
                   max   = 1,
                   value = dynamicValue()
       )
     ),
     shiny::mainPanel(

     )
  )
)
```

Now the problem with the above, is that it is resolved once and only once, like if the page is refreshed, the value remains persistent.

This can be fixed with something like this:

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  updateSliderInput(session,  "slider", value = dynamicValue() )

})
```

However, I have many plots, and they are rendering once, and then the slider is updated, causing everything to be invalidated and rendered a second time.

Can someone please explain to me how I can have a dynamic slider where the value is determined from a non-deterministic function, which is resolved every time the page is loaded, and before anything else is processed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lesser known feature in Shiny is that the static UI can be a function that gets called on every connection. It takes a single optional argument for a Rook-compatible HTTP request object (which you can ignore here).

I can't remember where this is documented, but it is kind of mentioned in https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/enableBookmarking.html

Wrap the UI in a function and the slider input gets a random value on every page load.

```
library(shiny)

dynamicValue = function(){
  runif(1)
}

ui <- function(request) {
  fluidPage(
    shiny::sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("slider",
                  "SliderInput",
                  min   = 0,
                  max   = 1,
                  value = dynamicValue()
      )
    ),
    shiny::mainPanel(
    )
  )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Bloody awesome. Exactly what I needed. Thanks.